# Is it possible to filter entries based on entry table field values?

Tags: craft3

I have an entry called "reviews" and within reviews I have a table field with several values. I would like to use the field values to display entry listings in a particular way.

First: I would like to be able to display entry listings so that if the field value is = x to display a particular set of entries.

Second: I would like to be able to display these values so that they are in an ascending order.

Comment: I think you will need to be more specific, perhaps give a code example?

Comment: @RoiAgenta

My entry type name is "reviews" and I have created a table field with the handle "reviewData". Within this table are a few columns columns with the handle names "age, provider, colour, style".  

As per my first question I would like to display all review entries with the colour = "blue" in one listing.  

For the second question I would like to display all review entires in ascending order according to their age value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, one possible way is the use the value of the colour field in an *if statement*, something this:

```
{# list rows that have "blue" in the colour field #}
{% for row in table.fieldName %}
{% if row.colour == 'blue' %} // probably best to make "blue" a variable
    <li>{{ row.age }} - {{ row.provider }} - etc.</li>
{% endif %}
```

In order to sort the table by a field value you will have to create a new array with the table data, then order by the name value. Will work that up for you in a bit

You could also do it with JavaScript, but that is nasty.

Here is the complete code using an Array to sort by the age field:

```
{% set tableBlock = [] %}
{% set tableRow = [] %} 

{% for row in entry.myTableField %} 
    {% if row.colour == "blue" %}

    {% set tableRow = {
        'age' : row.age,
        'colour' : row.colour,
        'provider' : row.provider
    } %}
{% set tableBlock = tableBlock|merge([tableRow]) %} 
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}

{% for row in tableBlock|sort %}
    {{row.age}} {{row.colour}} {{row.provider}}
{% endfor %}
```

For some reason the code block formatting is not working...

Comment: Glad to be of help!